# Clob as param for PL/SQL Java Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, clob, java-stored-procedures

I have a java stored procedure that takes in a clob representing a chunk of javascript and mins it.  The structure of the function calling the JSP is as follows:

```
function MIN_JS(pcl_js in clob) return clob as
  language java name 'JSMin.min(oracle.sql.CLOB) return oracle.sql.CLOB';
```

In the actual JSP, I have the following:

```
import oracle.sql.CLOB;

public class JSMin {
...
public static min(CLOB js) {
...
}
```

The problem I'm having is that whenever I pass a clob to JS_MIN, it is always interpreted as null inside the JSP.  I've checked the clob before calling JS_MIN annd it definitely has contents.  Any ideas as to what I'm missing?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Presumably your `JSMin` class is a wrapper to Douglas Crockford's java implementation.  It would be helpful if you posted sufficient details of your class for people to be able to re-create it.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, one of the javascript chunks I was sending was in fact null.  We have several packages that generate javascript for various controls and one is apparently still under development and wrapped in a way that it always returns null unless you are logged in as a particular user.

In my code, I loop across all the javascript packages, sending each to JS_MIN.  Everything was working peachy until the package still in development came along and passed null.  I added a simple check for null and everything works perfectly now.

So the short answer is: Doh!